# Wireguard client connects but not work

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, wireguard

I set a `Wireguard` server on `Ubuntu 22.04 64bit`. All things work perfect and client connects to server, but Transfer received is very low and not working.
[image]
Transfer : 1.02 KiB received, 242.96 KiB sent
I would add, I have a KVM VPS and client and server configs are set in this server.
This is Server conf file:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <contents-of-server-privatekey>
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = <contents-of-client-publickey>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
```

And Client conf file:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <contents-of-client-privatekey>
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8
[Peer]
PublicKey = <contents-of-server-publickey>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = "server public ip and ListenPort" (Ex: 172.16.0.12:51820)
PersistentKeepalive = 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same internal address for both client and server.

That can't work.

After that, make sure that you're setting up your client to route traffic through your wireguard tunnel at all.

Comment: Could you please post your suggestion or edit my configuration?

Comment: I can't, since I don't need what you need. However, "do not use the same address for server and client" is directly enough applicable, isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean 10.0.0.1/24?

Comment: yes, I do (that's the address you use.)

Comment: I changed the addresses but I still have the same problem

Comment: your question doesn't reflect that change, I can't guess what specifically you did, and you're not indicating whether or not you've addressed the second part of my answer at all.